# saving webview into local storage automatically

Tags: java, android, performance, webview, download

Webview loads every time I open it, Is there any way the web view files will be saved in local storage when I open the first time and when I open it again they don't need to be downloaded. means even if there is no internet they will open.

here's my java file. is there any way we can perform this task

```
package com.example.impwala;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;



public class chemistry1 extends AppCompatActivity {

    WebView chem1;
    ProgressDialog pDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chemistry1);

        if (haveNetwork())
        {
            init();
            listener();
        }
        else if (!haveNetwork())
        {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder =new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("No internet Connection");
            builder.setMessage("Please turn on internet connection to continue");
            builder.setNegativeButton("close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
            alertDialog.show();        }

    }

    public boolean haveNetwork()
    {
        boolean have_WIFI=false;
        boolean have_MobileData=false;

        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager=(ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo[] networkInfos=connectivityManager.getAllNetworkInfo();

        for (NetworkInfo info:networkInfos)
        {
            if (info.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI"))
                if(info.isConnected())
                    have_WIFI=true;
            if (info.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE"))
                if(info.isConnected())
                    have_MobileData=true;
        }
        return have_MobileData||have_WIFI;
    }
    private void init() {

        chem1 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.chem1);
        chem1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(chemistry1.this);
        pDialog.setTitle("PDF");
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        chem1.loadUrl("www.example.com");

    }


    private void listener() {
        chem1.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                pDialog.show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                pDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save your page as a web archive to your SD card storage in public Documents folder as,

```
File file;
String filenameExternal = "mypage";
if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED{
         file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS), filenameExternal);
}

chem1.saveWebArchive(file.toString()+".mht");
```

then, save the file name/path using shared preferences when the user leaves the app by overriding `@OnStop` method.
Finally, load your saved page by reading the file path from shared preference when the user re-opens the app.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                    chem1.loadUrl(file.toString()+".mht");
                } else {

                    loadOfflinePageBelowKitKat(position);
                }
```

loadOfflinePageBelowKitKat method

```
public void loadOfflinePageBelowKitKat(){

    String rawData = null;
    try{
        rawData = getStringFromFile(file.toString()+".mht");
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    chem1.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, rawData, "application/x-webarchive-xml", "UTF-8", null);

}
```

getStringFromFile method

```
public String getStringFromFile(String filePath) throws Exception{
    File file = new File(filePath);
    FileInputStream fInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
    String wantedString = convertStreamToString(fInputStream);
    fInputStream.close();
    return  wantedString;
}
```

I assumed you're familiar with working on shared preferences and Files.

Comment: Actually am not familiar with working on shared preferences and files, I am a newbie

Comment: No worries! It's pretty easy to work with shared preferences. Check this link, https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences and for working with saving/reading files to/from local storage check this link https://www.androidauthority.com/how-to-store-data-locally-in-android-app-717190/

Comment: I can't understand from the link,  just tell me where to put which code, That will be helpful though.

Comment: Use SharedPreference to save your webpage path as a String, then from the code I gave you above, replace "/your_path_from_sharedpref" to the value you read from the SharedPreference. Saving/Reading String values using SharedPreference will only require your little effort.

Comment: How to use this, TO save.   ```chem1.saveWebArchive("your/sd/path/"+"file_name"+".mht");``` What to use for filepath

Comment: I have updated my answer to include how the webpage can be saved to external storage, check it out!

Comment: By the way, if the page you're saving is always one (only last visited) you can save it when the user exits the app by overriding `onStop()` and calling `chem1.saveWebArchive(file.toString()+".mht");` inside `onStop()` That way, the latest webpage will be saved to the file path. Pretty much like how cache works.

Comment: **getExternalStorateState** doesn't work , and where to put that.if statement

Comment: You should declare the variables as a member variables as `private File file;
private String fileNameExternal = "mypage";` then the if statement has to be inside `onCreate()` method. Finally call `chem1.saveWebArchive(file.toString()+".mht");` in `onStop()` method. I did some typo to getExternalStorateState it should be getExternalStorageState.

Comment: Once you do the above one, you can load the saved page in `onCreate` as I stated in the second section of code in my answer. Remember to check if the file/webpage exists before you load.